# AngularJS ng-repeat on a tr with more than one object array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS. I have a problem with using ng-repeat. I have two objects and i want to iterate like:

first tr with obj1
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2

next tr with obj1
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2

next tr with obj1
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2
next tr with obj2

when i use

```
<tr ng-repeat ="obj in obj1"></tr>
```

after one iteration I want to repeate on obj 2 so that one tr will be of obj1 and another with obj2.

```
$scope.OBJ1=[
    {"primaryKey":1,"value":"something1"},
    {"primaryKey":2,"value":"something2"},
    {"primaryKey":3,"value":"something3"},
    {"primaryKey":4,"value":"something4"}
];

$scope.OBJ2=[
    {"primaryKey":1,"dayPart":"dinner"},
    {"primaryKey":1,"dayPart":"lunch"}
];
```

and expected result :

```
<tr>something1</tr>
<tr>dinner</tr>
<tr>lunch</tr>

<tr>something2</tr>
<tr>dinner</tr>
<tr>lunch</tr>

<tr>something3</tr>
<tr>dinner</tr>
<tr>lunch</tr>

<tr>something4</tr>
<tr>dinner</tr>
<tr>lunch</tr>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: some code to show ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard nested ng-repeats aren't possible here, as you can't create any wrapping DOM elements. However, what you want is possible with the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-directives:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="obj1 in OBJ1"><td>{{obj1.value}}</td></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="obj2 in OBJ2"><td>{{obj2.dayPart}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

or see [the example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7le72PsBhEiAoXvEkRRk?p=preview). I have added the *td* elements to make sure that the output is fairly valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not able to do that. It would be easier if you had a parent container for those - from Angular 1.2 [(ng-repeat docs)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) you can use ng-repeat-start/end directives, remember that if you are goin to reorganize your HTML. Also remember about [Undersore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [Lodash.js](http://lodash.com/)